# Is there any way to rename control file in oracle apart from shutting down oracle database? I need to rename control file

Tags: oracle, controlfile

The situation is like I have space in one of my control file I need to rename it but don't want to shutdown database. Is there any other way?
The classic way I follow is

```
Alter system set control_files='<file name>' scope=spfile;
shutdown immediate 
rename file from OS level 
startup
```

Is there any other way to rename control file?

Answer (score 1):

Not one that can be done online, not even in 12c. The method you mention is still current. If the database is working, why rename the file at all? Do it when you prepare for a maintenance downtime.